# How can I store the direction of a bus route in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, direction

I have 3 table: Route, Bus_stop, Route-Bus_stop 
Route: id, weekday, weekend 
Bus_stop: id, name 
Route-Bus_stop: primary key(order, time), foreign key: idRoute, idBus_stop

```
Insert into Route(id,weekday,weekend) values(1,1,1);
Insert into Route(id,weekday,weekend) values(2,1,1);

Insert into Bus_stop(id,name) values(1,'A');
Insert into Bus_stop(id,name) values(2,'B');
Insert into Bus_stop(id,name) values(3,'C');

Insert into Route-Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,routeo_rder,stoptime) values(1,1,0,7:00);
Insert into Route-Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,route_order,stoptime) values(1,2,1,7:10);
Insert into Route-Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,route_order,stoptime) values(1,3,2,7:30);

Insert into Route-Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,route_order,stoptime) values(2,3,0,15:00);
Insert into Route-Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,route_order,stoptime) values(2,2,1,15:10);
Insert into Route-Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,route_order,stoptime) values(2,1,2,15:20); 
-- this is only an example, my database is bigger.
```

One of the route goes A -> B -> C, the other C->B->A 
If the user wants to go A to C, how can I show only one of the routes with all of the bus stations to the destination? 
I've write this query, but this shows both of the routes.

```
select *idRoute from Route-Bus_stop where idBus_stop=1 or idBus_stop=3 order by time; // A -> C
```

This will show route A->C and C-> A. But I want only the A->C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don_'t rßuse reserved words  like ORDER or TIME as column names, so you spre the need to use backticks all the tiome

Also Route-Bus_stop is also not valid without Backticks.

For your query you keed a selfjoin to get starting point and end point

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Route_Bus_stop (
> idRoute int
> ,idBus_stop int 
> ,`order` int 
> ,`time` varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> Insert into Route_Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,`order`,`time`) values(1,1,0,'7:00');
> Insert into Route_Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,`order`,`time`) values(1,2,1,'7:10');
> Insert into Route_Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,`order`,`time`) values(1,3,2,'7:30');
>
> Insert into Route_Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,`order`,`time`) values(2,3,0,'15:00');
> Insert into Route_Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,`order`,`time`) values(2,2,1,'15:10');
> Insert into Route_Bus_stop(idRoute,idBus_stop,`order`,`time`) values(2,1,2,'15:20');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT r1.idRoute,r1.idBus_stop,r2.idBus_stop,r1.`time`, r2.`time`
> FROM Route_Bus_stop r1 INNER JOIN Route_Bus_stop r2
> ON r1.idRoute = r2.idRoute AND r1.`order` < r2.`order`
> WHERE r1.idBus_stop = 1 
> AND r2.idBus_stop = 3
> ```

> ```
> idRoute | idBus_stop | idBus_stop | time | time
> ------: | ---------: | ---------: | :--- | :---
>       1 |          1 |          3 | 7:00 | 7:30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0bd8a7c8788cc681f905091886c6bee)*